# Visual Studio 2013 weird stuff 0 becomes 0x0, 1 become 0x1 etc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I encountered weird stuff in Visual Studio.
When I tried to breakpoint on Javascript, the int values displays as HEX or something.

> 0 = 0x0,
> 1 = 0x1,
> 10 = 0xa
> etc...

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbFan.png)

Comment: that are the hexadecimal values of the specified number. is there any problem with this?

Comment: Right click the number in the Watch dialog and untick *hexadecimal display*

Comment: Yes. It should be showing the decimal value of it.

Comment: Thaaaanks Alex K..... !!!

Comment: This should be closed imo.

Answer (score 0):

In the Watch window you will see column names, Name and Value.  Right click on the Value header and deselect Hexadecimal Display.